# How to create RSACryptoServiceProvide using string private key

Tags: c#, .net, encryption, rsa, x509certificate

I **only** have a private key. i want to use it for signing data in RSA algorithm.
i know how to use certificate to sign data. but i don't any way to use private key in string format to create and use `RSACryptoServiceProvider`

My code looks something like this.

```
string privateKey = "-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----\nsometext\nsometext\nsometext\.....\n-----END PRIVATE KEY-----\n"
var rasAlg = new RSACryptoServiceProvider()// how can i use my private key here.
var signature = rasAlg.SignData(bytesArray, new SHA256CryptoServiceProvider());
```

**EDIT**

if any one can help me create X509Certificate then also it is fine.

Comment: one way is `RSA.FromXmlString(PrivateKey)` storing the key as XML

Comment: @Plutonix when i export it to XMLString then it outputs Modulus, Exponent, P, Q, DP, DQ, InverseQ, D. so how can i use private key, can you please explain

Comment: Modulus, P, Q, DP, DQ, InverseQ, and D -are- the private key. (And we most libraries require Exponent, too).  A public key is just Modulus and Exponent.

Answer (score 0):

i found bouncy castle library useful. i used bouncy castle pem reader to read it from string.

```
AsymmetricKeyParameter keyPair;

using (var reader = new StringReader(privateKey))
    keyPair = (AsymmetricKeyParameter)new PemReader(reader).ReadObject();
```